# SAS: what does J(x, y, z) mean

Tags: sas, sas-iml

I'm currently working on a SAS project and I stumbled upon a line, which I don't understand.

```
N = 1000
p = 0.05
PD = J(N, 1, p)
```

Is PD in this situation just a vector or what does it exactly do?
What does the J do?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found out that I'm just dumb and couldn't read the documentary..
https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=imlug&docsetTarget=imlug_langref_sect220.htm&locale=en

It's a function that defines how big the matrix in the output has to be.